# Targeting .Net 4.5 but Glimpse reports .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.5, asp.net-4.5, glimpse

I have an ASP.NET web app which targets .Net Framework 4.5. However Glimpse is reporting .Net 4.0 in its stats for the app. Is this normal? I know that 4.5 is an in-place replacement for 4.0. Is that the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The CLR version still reports as version 4.0. As long as you target version 4.5 in visual studio you will get the correct results. Even though the CLR version is still reports as 4.0